# How to filter an array with data with multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array that contains information. The data has a tag attribute on which I want to filter.

If the array contains data, the filter should be triggered on all data in the array. If there is no data in the array, then I get all the data from the array with data.

I need control array length for this I need to use `includes` for max data after filter 30

```js
//exist array with data
const arr = [
    { "value": "food", "tag": "food" },
    { "value": "drink1", "tag": "drink" },
    { "value": "drink2", "tag": "drink" },
    { "value": "empty tag data", "tag": null }
];

//example data from request with tags for filtering
const data1 = ["food", "drink"];
const data2 = [];

function example(arrayForSearch, needToFind) {
    //not work o.tag.includes(needToFind, 30)
    return arrayForSearch.reduce((a, o) => (o.tag.includes(needToFind)  && a.push(o.value), a), []);
}

// result (0, 1, 2) indexes from array
console.log(example(arr, data1));

// result all data from array
console.log(example(arr, data2));
```

Comment: `o.tag.includes(needToFind)` should be `needToFind.includes(o.tag)` and you should also check if `needToFind`is an empty array as you want to keep the object in that case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()` to return the items you wish. If `needToFind` is empty it will return all items in the array:

```js
    
const arr = [
    { "value": "food", "tag": "food" },
    { "value": "drink1", "tag": "drink" },
    { "value": "drink2", "tag": "drink" },
    { "value": "empty tag data", "tag": null }
];

const data1 = ["food", "drink"];
const data2 = [];

function example(arrayForSearch, needToFind) {
    // Return any item with a tag in the needToFind array _or_ if the needToFind array is empty.
    return arrayForSearch.filter(el => needToFind.length === 0 || needToFind.includes(el.tag));
}

console.log('data1 result:', example(arr, data1));
console.log('data2 result:', example(arr, data2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()` instead of `Array.reduce()` and switch the operand and the argument for `Array.includes()` function as followings:

```js
const arr = [
    { "value": "food", "tag": "food" },
    { "value": "drink1", "tag": "drink" },
    { "value": "drink2", "tag": "drink" },
    { "value": "empty tag data", "tag": null }
];

const data1 = ["food", "drink"];
const data2 = [];

function example(arrayForSearch, needToFind) {
    return Array.isArray(needToFind) && needToFind.length > 0 ? arrayForSearch.filter(item => needToFind.includes(item.tag)) : arrayForSearch
}

console.log(example(arr, data1));
console.log(example(arr, data2));
```

Comment: if i need array default size make controlled? for example max 2 items?

Comment: That is, the array is filtered and the default one should display the number of items that were passed to it in the config.
`function example(arrayForSearch, needToFind, maxItems)`

Comment: You can use `Array.slice(0, maxItems)` to get first `maxItems` items from the array. `const slicedArray = needToFind.slice(0, maxItems)`